# How can I $unset a sub-document that's part of another sub-document in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection containing documents of the following form:

```js
{
  tokens: {
      name: {
          value: "...",
      },
      ...
  }
}
```

`name` can be anything, and there can be multiple embedded documents assigned to different keys, all of which have a `value` field.

How do I `$unset` all embedded documents that have a certain `value`? `{ $unset: { "tokens.value": "test" } }` doesn't work, and nor does `"tokens.$[].value"` or `"tokens.$.value"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pipelined form of update, like this:

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "tokens": {
        $arrayToObject: {
          "$filter": {
            "input": {
              "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT.tokens"
            },
            "as": "item",
            "cond": {
              "$ne": [
                "$$item.v.value",
                "test"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  multi: true
})
```

[Playground link.](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MmOPoc4E6m0)

In this query, we do the following:

1. We convert `tokens` object to an array, using `$objectToArray`.
2. We filter out the array elements which have a `value` key present in embedded documents and have a value of `test` using `$filter`.
3. Finally we convert the filtered array back again to object, and assign it to `tokens` key.

Comment: Arrays can help, yes as we can reduce the to and fro conversion from `object to array` and `array to object`, for each document that is getting updated, and it can be significant. @rid